# How to put caption text to left side on Checkbox, Radiobuttons and Slider?

Tags: java, vaadin

How to put caption text to left side on Checkbox, Radiobuttons and Slider in Vaadin 8 without CSS?

Comment: If you add Fields into FormLayout instead of e.g. VerticalLayout, this is done automatically.

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow. Please add to your question what you have tried so far, and why it didn't work. You could also add some code.

Comment: I dont want use FL, I use CSSLayout or HL or VL and I put checkbox and next slider, but text I want put on the left like group that CHbox and Slider pass together, there are some ALIGN to right or top on other components like Button, but no solution for put text to left

Answer (score 0):

As Tatu Lund pointed out in the comments, this can be done with a `FormLayout`. Please refer to the Vaadin 8 framework [documentation](https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/layout/layout-formlayout.html). In case that you need to have a form field label for checkboxes etc. you could wrap these fields in `HorizontalLayout`. This done for example in the [Valo theme demo](https://demo.vaadin.com/valo-theme/#!forms). Source can be found [here](https://github.com/vaadin/framework/blob/master/uitest/src/main/java/com/vaadin/tests/themes/valo/Forms.java#L94-L111) (the demo is Vaadin 7 but it works in Vaadin 8, too).

Comment: I understand but I dont want use too much layout inside, more useless layouts means more DOMs and less effective code and speed, can Vaadin team make put ALIGN texts to components on left side too?